# How to create an Email Subscription input in WordPress?

Tags: php, jquery

I can't find a good guide to create a simple input, that allows the user to submit his email and add it to a user's email's database in WordPress and also auto send the user a confirm email.

I'm building a theme in WordPress from scratch, and I'm using PHP and jQuery plus Bootstrap (not that it's important).

Comment: Use the Contact 7 plugin. Generate a shortcode and put it where you want.

Comment: @Jos theres alot of CONTACT 7 plugins, can you direct me ?

Comment: Apologies, I meant [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/).

Comment: @Jos it doesnt work very well for me, to complicated. I need something simple with no plugin or short code. I need with PHP to create one input that you enter a value and its get inside my database..

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the place for plugin recommendations, there are several 'subscriber' plugins available in the repository. I've used the "Email Subscribers" plugin for a while. It works well, although there was some difficulties with it when they did a major revision to their version 4. (Which is a tale about fully testing code.)

If you don't want a plugin, then you will have to write your own code. A bit complex to describe here. But there are many 'googles' (or 'bings' or 'ducks') that can help you with the process. So start there.